# Removing empty spaces in a table

Tags: tables, elsarticle

I have a table and unfortunately in the right side of that empty areas are existed. How can I remove these areas and make the table fixed to its numbers.(in the real table, there are several rows)

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{table*}
\caption{some words.}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{3}{C}c@{}}
    \toprule
    Datasets     & Precision & Recall & F-measure & MAE \\ 
    \midrule
    SVO   & 0.7291 & 0.1441& 0.2411& 0.4042 \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `tabularx` environment to `tabular`, and use it as `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{C}@{}}`.

Comment: How do you define the `C` column type?

Comment: @Bernard , because I'm new in Latex, where can I see that how C column type is defined?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ , the table becomes so long and "MAE" goes to the next lind and below "Datasets".

Comment: @Ben25 It is not a standard column type. Maybe it is defined  in the code of the  `elsarticle` class.

Comment: @Ben25 Try `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{c}@{}}` instead. If that still doesn't work, provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Did you recieve any error message when trying to compile your document (such as "Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.")? If so, please do not ignore error messages.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: Your two suggestions just include 4 columns while the original table seems to need at least 5 column. `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{c}@{}}` might be a better choice.

Comment: @Ben25: Only use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` if you want a table that is as wide as `\textwidth`. If you want a narrower table, just use a simple `tabular`.

Comment: @leandriis , Yes, I face with many errors like this :Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used. \end{tabularx}. How can I fix them.

Comment: @Ben25: You get this error message because latex does not konw the `C` type column. Where did you get that from? This is also the reason for Bernard's question about the on of the `C` type column. What to do instead entirely depends on the desired output. I would suggest using `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{c}@{}}`. (I used `c` instead of `C` here.)

Comment: @leandriis , you suggestion to "muzimuzhiZ" doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben25: The following code works perfectly fine for me: `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{some words.}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{c}@{}}
    \toprule
    Datasets     & Precision & Recall & F-measure & MAE \\ 
    \midrule
    SVO   & 0.7291 & 0.1441& 0.2411& 0.4042 \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
 \end{document}` Did you do something different? What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get error messages or does the output not look like you want?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. I missed the last `c` column in `{@{}l*{3}{C}c@{}}`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering%<-----------------------added new
\caption{some words.}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{c}c@{}}
    \toprule
    Datasets     & Precision & Recall & F-measure & MAE \\ 
    \midrule
    SVO   & 0.7291 & 0.1441& 0.2411& 0.4042 \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You could combine `*{3}{c}c` to `*{4}{c}`.

Comment: +1 yes of course --but i have tried to change as little as possible so that newcomers can follow